# ruby rmagick FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs"

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I run in loop converting of pdf scans (base64 data) to jpg images with rmagick with this code

```
Magick::Image.read_inline(data) do
          self.quality = 100
          self.density = '150'
          self.interlace = Magick::NoInterlace
        end.each_with_index do |img, i|
          img.write(rpvs_dir+"temp-#{i}.jpg")
        end
```

it looks it works fine but after 10-15 documents it starts throwing this error

> FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE
>   -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4
>   "-r150x150"  "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-17139yIssgZl8Dg7O%d"
>   "-f/tmp/magick-17139VEtM2IeDiPfF" "-f/tmp/magick-17139ANIid4R9Yoov"'
>   (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/461

then some documents are fine and it starts again.
is it related to memory or what might be the problem? from error message I cannot find out what might be wrong

Comment: Does `read_inline` use a passed block? I can't find any docs that would indicate so. (You could insert a `raise foo` in the block and see if it ever gets called.) If those `self` methods are intended to be run on the image, you could try calling them on the `img` object in the `each_with_index` block. Also, one of the tmp files in the command is probably the input file; maybe you could inspect it to look for size, validity, etc.

Comment: it looks the problem was with the memory..I upgraded ruby from 2.2.3 to 2.2.10 and now memory usage gets down by 50% and no error after hundreds of documents in loop

Comment: I'm still curious to know if your `self.` calls are ever executed?  Also, I believe Ruby 2.2 is no longer supported. If you can upgrade to a later version you'll have access to security updates, etc.

Comment: thats a good question, now I updated to ruby 2.4.4 and .read_inline method provides me empty array even my data variable has base64 data..it does even without block, just simple @myfile = Magick::Image.read_inline(data)

Comment: Is it possible that there is data but it does not constitute a valid image, and that's why the array is empty? Are you testing this with the same data or different data at different times?

Comment: I am testing same data on different servers...2 servers process ok, one server returns empty array

Comment: ok I found a problem, I was missing ghostscript installed on the machine where it was returning empty array...strange it does not show error, just empty array
thanks for trying to help me